# How do I make the registered symbol not display an underline?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble where I can't display part of a word with an underline and part of it without. I want the "registered" symbol to not have an underline.

HTML:

```
<h3>Basecamp<span class="sup">&reg;</span></h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 {
font-size: 21px;
color: #369;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 5px;
}

.sup {
vertical-align: super;
text-decoration: none; /*how do i get this off?!*/
font-size: 50%;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Hi check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WYwv2/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/WYwv2/3/

Why does this work? Let's have a look at [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props)

> ... For block containers that establish an inline formatting context, the decorations are propagated to an anonymous inline element that wraps all the in-flow inline-level children of the block container. For all other elements it is propagated to any in-flow children. Note that **text decorations are not propagated to** floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as **inline blocks** and inline tables.

Comment: very cool, so would this work in ie6 (don't care about it, just wondering)?

Comment: @DavidNguyen Not sure. <del>Un</del>fortunately I don't have any IE6 to test that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work unless you separate the other text from the reg symbol.

```
h3 {
font-size: 21px;
color: #369;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 5px;
}

h3 span {
text-decoration: underline;
}


h3 span.sup {
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: super;
font-size: 50%;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

`<h3><span>Basecamp</span><span class="sup">&reg;</span></h3>`

http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/yTP9q/2/ <-- updated thanks Rohit

Answer (score 0):

see the demo :-    [**DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/L3KfMUMz)

```
h3 span {
vertical-align: super;
text-decoration: none; 
font-size: 50%;
font-weight: 400;
display:inline-block;
}
```