# CSS text-decoration hierarchy

Tags: css

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I'm enough of a CSS neophyte that I don't even know exactly what to search for.

I'm trying to modify text-decoration within a block by adding a `span`, and it's not working. How come? I can add a new text-decoration within the `span`, but I can't subtract the old one.

```
<h1 class="strikethrough">
    stricken<span class="no-strikethrough"> no strike</span>
</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zV3ga/2/

Is there a way I can achieve my goal? I'd like to inherit all the properties of the `h1` *except* the text-decoration, so I'd really prefer to have my "no strike" text inside that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to keep the first part with a atrile and the second part without a strike.

So do this

```
<h1>
    <span class="strikethrough">stricken</span> no strike
</h1>
```

And one more thing.
Using hyphens in the class name is fine and dandy if youre just in CSS but when you move to Javascript that will cause problems (as far as my knowlege goes). So practice that way

Comment: I know more JS than CSS, as it turns out. Hyphens in the class name don't cause any more difficulty than hyphens in the CSS attributes (e.g., `text-decoration`) - and this particular site is entirely static anyway.

Comment: And +1 for the obvious answer. It won't work for some folks, but it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why these people are saying it isn't *possible.* This is entirely possible via CSS.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/y5bRS/

```
.strikethrough {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: blue;
}

.no-strikethrough {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}
.no-strikethrough:before {
    content: '\00a0';
}
```

Comment: Not working in IE8, not working in IE7. If you care about supporting browsers in use today, this may not be an appropriate solution.

Comment: This does work, I remember seeing an answer to a similar question with more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618639/how-do-i-make-the-registered-symbol-not-display-an-underline/13618800#comment18675806_13618800

Comment: @SetSailMedia it works just fine in IE8 http://cl.austin.pe/image/1H361r3p2D39

Comment: @AustinPray take a look here to see where it's supported and where it's not, IE 8 and older does not... http://browsershots.org/http://devstage.co/strike.html

Answer (score 2):

Strikethrough applies to the entire parent element. It's rendered the full width of the parent, no way to "turn off" for a child.

Any reason not to use HTML markup?

`<h1>Partial <strike>stricken</strike></h1>`

HTML5:

`<h1>Partial <del>stricken</del></h1>`

Comment: +1 goes to this answer. Quick and easy.

Comment: Isn't the usual reason for using CSS instead of HTML markup a good enough one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in its current form, you are putting a strike on the H1 which is the parent of span, you can't have a child reverse it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the case. Think of it as like applying a border to <h1> then specifying no border on the `<span>`, the `!important` keyword won't help because technically the `<span>` never had a border to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1 >
    <span class="strikethrough">stricken</span><span class="no-strikethrough"> no strike</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Duh! Thanks - this will work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is useful for you but you may try striking span's inner.

```
<h1 class="no-strikethrough">
   <span class="strikethrough">stricken</span> no strike
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it is the most optimized approach

```
<h1>stricken
    <span class="test">no strike</span>

</h1>

.test {
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
    color: blue;
}

h1  {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}
```